# JQuery event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, mouseevent, mouseenter

I have a button on the page. Here is the code.

```
var button = "<button title = " + obj.hostname + "&#44;&#32;" + gpu.toUpperCase() +
        // " data-content = \"" + img1 + "\"" +
        " data-id=\"" + detailed_summary + "\"" +
        " data-text = \"" + obj.hostname + ", " + gpu.toUpperCase() + ", " + metric_name[metric] + ":&#32;" + display_val + "\"" +
        " class=\"btn " + button_state + " gpu btn-lg open-InfoModal\"" +
        " data-toggle=\"modal\" " +
        " rel=\"popover\" " +
        " data-target=\"#hostInfo\" " +
        " href=\"#infoModal\"></button>";
```

When I try this jQuery code, it doesn't work.

```
$("button.btn").on("mouseenter", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("MouseEnter"); 
    });
```

I have changed the selector to `.btn`, `gpu`, `btn-lg`, `open-InfoModal`. But it doesn't work. I also have tried changing `mouseover`, `hover`.But When I change the selector to `li`, then It works.

There are 180 buttons wrapped in one `li`. I don't want the output to work with `li`

Any Idea?

Comment: Are you adding buttons dynamically?

Comment: I am adding html in jquery...

Comment: try with setting class to only "btn"

Comment: I tried, but the result is still the same, it doesn't detect, I don't know why. It's weird

Comment: Make sure you've written above event code in document ready function.$(document).ready(function(){}) Can you provide entire code

Comment: Here is the code `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on("mouseenter", function(){
        console.log("M");
    });
});`
I also have tried `(window).ready` or `(window).load`

Comment: I am inserting this button inside a function, when I tried to use this jquery inside that function, then it worked. I think it is something to do with scope.

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown above is the button markup in a variable. You did not show us whether or not you actually add the markup to the DOM and if so, when in relation to the event binding.

If you are adding the button to the DOM after the event is bound:

```
$( document.body ).append( button ); //for example
```

Then you need to bind the event as follows (event delegation):

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseenter","button.btn", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("MouseEnter"); 
  });
});
```